# Temporary Variables in Firebase Security rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

So I'm setting up the firebase security rules for my project and for the user to have read access to a room, we need to make sure they are part of that organization. So I have a security rule like this:

`root.child('organizations').child(data.child('organization_id').val()).child('user_ids').hasChild(auth.uid)`

Not only is this really ugly, there are several other rules in the same statement (separated by &&/||) which have start with `root.child('organizations').child(data.child('organization_id').val())` to access data from the organization variable associated with this room.

This leads to some **UGLY** security rules, is there any way I can make temporary variables or something like that so I can make this a lot more readable? Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question (and my answer below) is about Firebase Realtime Database and its security rules.

If you're looking for using local variables in Cloud Firestore or Cloud Storage security rules, that **is** nowadays possible. Have a look at the blog post [New improvements to Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/06/new-firestore-security-rules-features.html) and the [release note on Local Variables](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/security-rules#february_13_2020).

---

The Firebase Security rules language for Realtime Database doesn't have support for custom variables. This indeed leads to lots of duplication between rules.

The best solution is to write your rules in a higher-level language, that compiles into Firebase Security rules. The most well-known ones are [Blaze](https://github.com/firebase/blaze_compiler) (the grand-daddy of them all), [Butane](https://github.com/aputinski/butane) (not from Firebase itself) and [Bolt](https://github.com/firebase/bolt) (new and under very active development).

Bolt for example allows you to define (global) [functions](https://github.com/firebase/bolt/blob/master/docs/language.md#functions-and-methods), which can easily encapsulate the repeated snippet and much more.

Comment: This is just the kind of thing I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: Bolt is most likely to be adopted as the recommended approach in the future. Start there.

Comment: outdated answer

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski Did you consider posting an up to date answer too?

Comment: I have not no, but that's because someone else did.

Answer (score 3):

Since June 2020 the answer is [Yes, you can have local variables](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/06/new-firestore-security-rules-features.html) (answering in case it's helpful to others)

From the firebase blog linked above

> Local variables have been one of the most requested features in Rules, and they're now available within functions.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: looks like the link in this answer is for firestore, not the realtime database (the one referenced in the question)

Answer (score 1):

In Bolt, you could write your rule like this:

```
type Room {
  organization_id: String,

  read() { isUserInOrg(this.organization_id) }
}

isUserInOrg(org_id) { root.organizations[org_id].user_ids[auth.uid] }
```